# react native sound Not working on Windows: Cannot read property 'IsAndroid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sound, react-native-windows

I'm working on project for android and windows using react native CLI and I want to play sound when the user clicks a butto. For that, I've used `react-native-sound` as the most famous library to play sounds on react native and the it supports windows as they say on their [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound);

It works fine on android, but on Windows it produces an error:

```
var RNSound = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNSound;
var IsAndroid = RNSound.IsAndroid;
```

[image]

I've tried to log the `require('react-native').NativeModules` but the `RNSound wasn't there.

Is there any way to make it work on windows or can suggest some other way to play sounds on both android and windows using react native?

Comment: [Don't post images of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3750257)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after searching and asking for help my teammate Ahmed Shatat have a deep look into their Repo and find a branch works fine on windows, android and IOS,

in the package json it should look like

```
"react-native-sound": "zmxv/react-native-sound#731/head",
```

and it will work

Comment: this is not working for me .

Comment: error: pathspec '731/head' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: i added this "react-native-sound": "zmxv/react-native-sound#731/head", in the dependencies section in package.json

Comment: This makes no sense. "zmxv/react-native-sound#731/head" is not a package version